# How to convert StyleCop rules from version 4.3 or 4.5 to 4.6?

Tags: c#, coding-style, stylecop

My team are going to new version of resharper, it's 6.

And our old rules don't work on StyleCop 4.6. Our rules was worked on 4.5 version.

Any one know most easier way to convert StyleCop rules from version 4.3 (or 4.5) to 4.6?

Comment: Could you please specify, where exactly troubles are? What specific parts of code in your rules do not compile?

Comment: @OlegShuruev , I solved problem with my self (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080001/how-to-convert-stylecop-rules-from-version-4-3-or-4-5-to-4-6/8081674#8081674) my config didn't have 'Parsers' tags and had a different version property. It is all differences between that versions)

Comment: @OlegShuruev , StyleCop sat that rules have a wrong format and I need to reset it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solution:

```
    <StyleCopSettings Version="105">
      <Parsers>
        <Parser ParserId="StyleCop.CSharp.CsParser">
          <ParserSettings>
            <CollectionProperty Name="GeneratedFileFilters">
              <Value>\.g\.cs$</Value>
              <Value>\.generated\.cs$</Value>
              <Value>\.g\.i\.cs$</Value>
            </CollectionProperty>
          </ParserSettings>
        </Parser>
      </Parsers>
      <Analyzers>
       <!--------Here your old rules----->
      </Analyzers>
    </StyleCopSettings>
```

Thay also add two new rules: SA1517 and SA1518. That will be on your own.

Answer (score 2):

It's much the same as upgrading any framework on which your code depends:

1. Change your references to the new version.
2. Try to compile.
3. Adjust for breaking changes until compilation works.
4. Run your tests.
5. Adjust for breaking changes until your tests pass.
6. Deploy, then adjust for breaking changes until the users stop complaining.

There's no magic formula for avoiding this sort of thing, particularly for an free tool where maintaining backward compatilibility is not a priority...